# why softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2 return cost even same value

Tags: tensorflow, softmax, cross-entropy

i have tested "softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2"
with a random number

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,5])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,5])
softmax = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=x,labels=y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    feedx=[[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5],[0.,0.,0.,0.,1.]]
    feedy=[[1.,0.,0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.,0.,1.]]
    softmax = sess.run(softmax, feed_dict={x:feedx, y:feedy})
    print("softmax", softmax)
```

console "softmax [1.8194163 0.9048325]"

what i understand about this function was
This function only returns cost when logits and labels are different.

then why it returns 0.9048325 even same value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2` works is that it does softmax on your `x` array to turn the array into probabilities:

[image]

where `i` is the index of your array. Then the output of `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2` will be the dotproduct between `-log(p)` and the labels:

[image]

Since the labels are either 0 or 1, only the term where the label is equal to one contributes. So in your first sample, the softmax probability of the first index is

[image]

and the output will be

[image]

Your second sample will be different, since `x[0]` is different than `x[1]`.

Comment: dear user, is the above euqation for "softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2" loss function? is it work using this function? because i need the euqation, its really helpful for me.

Comment: [This](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/9302) post has a more formal definition for the cross-entropy, but it reduces to the above expression.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.nn.softmax_cross_etnropy_with_logits_v2` as per [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2) expects unscaled inputs, because it performs a `softmax` operation on `logits` internally. Your second input [0, 0, 0, 0, 1] thus is internally softmaxed to something roughly like [0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.4] and then, cross entropy for this logit and the true label [0, 0, 0, 0, 1] is computed to be the value you get